# How do I view a list of devices from the command line in Windows

Tags: command-line

I want to use the Windows command line to enumerate through devices connected to a computer and return information.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do this by using the devcon.exe utility.

It ships with [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852361). Select just the Tools in the installation wizard if you do not need the rest of the kit.

Refer to [The DevCon command-line utility functions as an alternative to Device Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) for specific commands. I imagine you would start with something like

```
devcon find *
```

Answer (score 6):

In 2023 Microsoft [suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-migration) using PnPUtil instead of devcon. PnPUtil is [included](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil) in every version of Windows, starting with Windows Vista.

To view a list of devices from command line use:

```
pnputil /enum-devices /connected
```

More usage examples can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples).

Answer (score 2):

## Try PowerShell's Get-PnpDevice

This seems to be the more modern version of things like `devcon.exe` or `pnputil.exe`.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdevice