# How to get a list of connected devices?

Tags: windows-7

I'm experiencing a strange phenomenon. Every now and then (perhaps once per hour on average) my Win7 box emits the "Device connected" system sound (the one you get when you plug in a USB device) for no apparent reason. This can happen several times in a session, and there never is a "Device removed" sound in-between. I have no idea what's causing this. I'm not sure, but I think this only started after I had installed Dropbox.

Is there any way to find out which device Windows thinks has just been connected when it plays that sound?

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/414280/how-do-i-view-a-list-of-devices-from-the-command-line-in-windows), but the WDK requires me to install Visual Studio first, and I don't want to do that if possible. Isn't there something I could do with Sysinternals or some other tool?

Comment: +1 - I have experienced this too. Very annoying. But I have found no connection to Dropbox. I *usually* get it to stop by unplugging all my usb devices and reconnecting them. Sadly it doesn't always work.